# Why can bcrypt.hashpw be used both for hashing and verifying passwords?

Tags: python, hash, salt, bcrypt

Using [`bcrypt`](https://github.com/dstufft/bcrypt) with Python 2.7, I can see that the example uses the `bcrypt.hashpw` to both hash a password for storage and verify that the given password matches a hashed one, like so:

### Hashing

```
import bcrypt
password = b"somepassword"
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())
```

Ok, so far so good.  The given password is now hashed using bcrypt, so it is a string of hashed bytes.

### Verifying

Now, here's the part that confuses me: to check that a plaintext password matches a hashed password, the *same* function is used, using the hashed password as a salt:

```
if bcrypt.hashpw(password, hashed) == hashed:
    print("It Matches!")
else:
    print("It Does not Match :(")
```

### What's happening?

Shouldn't the results of both `bcrypt.hashpw` calls be different, since the input salts are different?

The only reasonable answer I can think of is that the salt is truncated to a fixed length before being prepended to the hashed password.  That way, when using the result of the hash, only the generated salt is left (after stripping off the trailing hashed password), and the result of hashing the password with the truncated salt is the same as the original.  I don't have any evidence to support this, though.

Why does this work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the expression `bcrypt.hashpw(password, hashed)` only the first couple of characters of `hashed` are used for the salt, not the entire string.

For instance, in this example how the output of `hashpw()` begins with the salt:

```
salt1 = b"$2a$12$w40nlebw3XyoZ5Cqke14M."

print "salt1:", salt1
print "hash1:", bcrypt.hashpw(password, salt1)
```

prints:

```
salt1: $2a$12$w40nlebw3XyoZ5Cqke14M.
hash1: $2a$12$w40nlebw3XyoZ5Cqke14M.d.7cdO2wJhr/K6ZSDjODIxLrPmYzY/a
```

so there is a convention where the salt only goes up the first period or the first 29 characters.

Answer (score 8):

The `hashpw` function returns the salted hash (iterated many times, following `bcyrpt` spec), preceeded by the salt used (and with a dot as seperator).

```
In : salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
In : all(salt == bcrypt.hashpw(pw,salt)[:len(salt)] for pw in ('','12345','asdfgh'))
Out: True
```

If the second argument to `bcrypt.hashpw` is recognized as of the form `VALID_SALT.VALID_HASH`, then the salt is automagically set to `VALID_SALT`, thus producing the same salt-hash-pair as the original password on identical `pw` input.

Comment: For python3, the strings need to be encoded before hashing: all(salt == bcrypt.hashpw(pw.encode(),salt)[:len(salt)] for pw in ('','12345','asdfgh'))