# How to check a bcrypt password

Tags: python, bcrypt

I have the following password stored in a database:

```
$2a$10$0T6qQvTwZoa8hG9Gw.iuiuJ4cXPdfnO21h.meL9QIqwIhjNx2WNHa
```

It is a bcrypt password stored by the following java command:

```
String passwordHash = BCrypt.hashpw(user.getPassword(), BCrypt.gensalt());
```

I know this password is "asdfasdf" because I entered it in. How would I get a "True" response from python using its Bcrypt library. Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
import bcrypt
password = "asdfasdf"
previous_hash = "$2a$10$0T6qQvTwZoa8hG9Gw.iuiuJ4cXPdfnO21h.meL9QIqwIhjNx2WNHa"
bcrypt.checkpw(password, previous_hash)
False
```

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: @JohnZwinck -- 2.7 -- it seems that if I create a bcrypt in django it starts with `$2b`, whereas in this java app it starts with `$2a`. Do you think that could be related?

Comment: Try running `hashpw()` on the exact same password and salt.  In other words, generate a salt from either Python or Java and pass it explicitly to `hashpw()` in both languages and compare the output.  Do they match?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413248/why-can-bcrypt-hashpw-be-used-both-for-hashing-and-verifying-passwords

Comment: Relevant: [insecure-versions-of-crypt-hashes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20541/insecure-versions-of-crypt-hashes/20543#20543) and [invalid-salt-revision-when-comparing-python-generated-hash-with-raw-password-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095166/invalid-salt-revision-when-comparing-python-generated-hash-with-raw-password-in)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
previous_hash == bcrypt.hashpw(password, previous_hash)
```